# SQL Server : Nvarchar to Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with two columns, one is of type `Varchar` and the other in `NVarchar`.

I want to update all the rows so VarcharField = NVarcharField.

It won't let me because some of the rows contain chars that are not allowed in `varchar` column with the current code page.

How can I find these rows?

Is it possible to remove any char that doesn't fit the specific code page I'm using?

SQL Server 2012.

Comment: You really want to remove characters that are not supported? Why do you need this at all?

Comment: I can't work with Nvarchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [Gordon's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367310/284240) doesn't work because you get question marks from `TRY_CONVERT` instead of the expected `NULL`, try this approach:

```
SELECT IsConvertible = CASE WHEN NULLIF(REPLACE(TRY_CONVERT(varchar(max), N'人物'), '?',''), '') IS NULL
                       THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
```

If you need it as filter for the rows that can't be converted:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE NULLIF(REPLACE(TRY_CONVERT(varchar(max), t.NVarcharField), '?',''), '') IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find the rows by attempting to convert the `nvarchar()` col to `varchar()`:

```
select nvarcharcol
from t
where try_convert(varchar(max), nvarcharcol) is null;
```

Comment: Does it reall work? Because when i use it `try_convert` returns `??` not null for chinese letters. Tested with:  `SELECT try_convert(varchar(max), N'人物')`

Comment: Why would this conversion ever fail? This answer doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, maybe your current code page support chinese?

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

to find the rows with values that are not supported by `varchar`

```
declare @strText nvarchar(max)
set @strText = 'Keep calm and say தமிழன்டா'

select  cast(@strText as varchar(max)) col1 , N'Keep calm and say தமிழன்டா' col2
```

Here `@strText` has non-english chars, When you try to `cast` that into `varchar` the non-english chars turns into `????`. So the `col1` and `col2` are not equal.

```
select nvar_col
from tabl_name
where nvar_col != cast(nvar_col as varchar(max))
```

**Is it possible to remove any char that doesn't fit the specific code page I'm using?**

```
update tabl_name 
    set nvar_col = replace(cast(nvar_col as varchar(max)),'?','')
where nvar_col != cast(nvar_col as varchar(max))
```

Replace `?` with empty string and update them.